# How to model and solve Quadratic assignment model

Tags: gurobi

I have a question regarding to programming simple quadratic assignment problem with Gurobi? As you know the objective function is not linear. Can we model and solve it with Gurobi (I am using Gurobi/python interface)

Comment: You've seen their example: http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/6.5/examples/qp_py.html

Comment: Am I mistaken, or can this be modeled as just a linear program with n^2 binary variables - no need for quadratic constraints or objective.

Comment: No I can't I give up.